# Home Network- Gigabit not working with 5 out of 6 patch cables

Tags: networking, router, lan, home-networking

Setting up a netgear n600 (WNDR3700) in my home. I have tried connecting two PCs to the LAN and am only getting 100mb/s with most of my patch cables(all are cat5e). I was only able to achieve 1Gb/s with 1 of my cables(which is actually a few feet to short for my shortest run). Both PCs have gigabit capability.

Is this a common issue? What are the chances that 5 out of 6 cat5e cables are bad? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Almost definitely a cable issue. I would at least go out and pickup a few good quality CAT6 patch cables and continue to troubleshoot with them. Also eliminate all cross-talk by making sure you have clear run without power cables crossing/looped with the ethernet cables.

Comment: Also, try and set both PCs manually to Gigabit in the network card properties just to see what happens.

Comment: Gonna try some cat6 cable. How can I manually set NIC props in win7?

Answer (score 0):

How long are the cable runs? Realistically, with cat5e, you should stay under 300 feet (max is around 325, but even in ideal home conditions, you won't get close to that and keep gigabit).

How did you secure the cables? For cables to retain their integrity, you should make sure that the sheathing is never noticeably creased when securing them (ie, staple guns are a bad idea).

What are the duplex settings on all concerned devices? You will get link at the lowest duplex rate, and in cases where both are asserting specific speeds that differ (ie, one is trying 1000, one is trying 100), you can get all sorts of weird issues.

Comment: Runs are less than 30 ft